# Java 7 Screen Drawing Memory Error

Tags: java

I am seeing this issue when trying to start my java swing application.

I am running on OSX 10.8 and JDK 7u45

Any help on understanding where things are breaking down would be really awesome.

```
2013-12-12 10:52:01.505 java[1097:707] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
2013-12-12 10:52:01.507 java[1097:707] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84a55b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff861a73f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84ae9f49 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000158d30539 JNFCallVoidMethod + 209
4   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000159e0bbde -[AWTWindow _deliverMoveResizeEvent] + 349
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84a07eda _CFXNotificationPost + 2554
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff879387b6 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff83a1149e -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 2322
8   liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000159e0e2d5 __Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPlatformWindow_nativeSetNSWindowBounds_block_invoke_1 + 284
9   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000158d325f5 +[JNFRunLoop _performCopiedBlock:] + 20
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff879825ca __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849d4b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849d4455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849f77f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849f70e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff883a2eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff883a2c52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff883a2ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff839e2533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff839e1df2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
20  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000159ea26f4 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff839d91a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
22  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000159ea2557 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
23  liblwawt.dylib                      0x0000000159dfaba9 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 873
24  Foundation                          0x00007fff879825ca __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849d4b31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849d4455 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849f77f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849f70e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
29  java                                0x000000010a54b3b0 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
30  java                                0x000000010a545b5c JLI_Launch + 1952
31  java                                0x000000010a54b70d main + 101
32  java                                0x000000010a5453b4 start + 52
33  ???                                 0x000000000000000d 0x0 + 13
)
ERROR          2013-12-12 10:52:01,553   CAUGHT EXCEPTION ::      dtv.util.LoggingRunnableWrapper.run(LoggingRunnableWrapper.java:40) [AWT-EventQueue-0]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: can't create offscreen surface
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.initSurfaceNow(OGLSurfaceData.java:298)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData.access$000(OGLSurfaceData.java:98)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLSurfaceData$1.run(OGLSurfaceData.java:324)
at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
```

Comment: Can you provide a part of the code too ?

Comment: I'm looking at a similar issue at the moment. You've either got a very big window you are trying to open or you have a very large image that you are trying to render?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug of JDK. See [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055839)